# Selected to active baking produces stretched faces - Blender

Tags: uv, normals, baking

I have an issue when baking
[image: issues_with_stretched_faces]

Texture faces are stretched after baking "selected to active". It only bakes the textures if the normals are flipped on my active object(scanned mesh).
Things I tried:

- resetting normal vectors,
- set from faces,
- recalculate outside,
- tried relaxing the UVs with TexTools,
- UV packing is done with UVPackmaster3 (no rotation enabled/no fixed scale / NormalizeIslands is enabled)
- tried regular UV unwrap with Blender
- tried smart UV project
- all transforms are applied on both objects
- no modifiers are added.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I fixed the issue by using a cage. Duplicating my scanned mesh, scale it down on Z axis, and used it as a cage in the baking process(Max ray distance was set to 250m in my case).

Set the Normals to point in the correct way, that meant the cage was supposed to be placed above my scan mesh.

Objects places in Blender on Z axis:

- Top > High poly mesh (texture from which you want to bake)
- Middle > Cage
- Bottom > Scanned mesh (or low poly if you want to call it that or texture to be baked to)

Hope the explanation is clear enough.

IoanF